# Redirect url to home page with trailing dots

Tags: .htaccess, url

Google webmaster showing some duplicate url, 
They are

```
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&n_id=148&ite..
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&n_id=156&item..
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_games&view=detail&vid=170&itemid..
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_play&view=detail&vid=175&it..
```

To remove them - i feel the best way is to redirect to home page for any url containing **..** at end of url

tried putting this condition, but it does not work too

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^(..*)\.htm$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Correct url structure are

```
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&n_id=148&Itemid=2
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=detail&n_id=156&Itemid=2
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_games&view=detail&vid=170&Itemid=3
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_play&view=detail&vid=175&Itemid=4
```

any suggestions pls ... many thnx

**Edit on 13th Sep**
Hello Anubhav,

If we have redirect these URL to 404 page then is below command in htaccess correct

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?.+?\.\.
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,L,R=404]
```

Comment: You've asked 7 questions and haven't responded by your comments or accepted any one of them. Don't you think you need to be more responsive to the folks who spend their time to answer your questions.

Comment: Agreed, however i do reply whereever the revert seems a probable solution or has query attached to it. With your feedback, let me close all pending one where the solutions were taken up as answers. thanks. In meanwhile - can you suggest for the question reffered.

Comment: Ok hw are these URLs duplicate even if they have different n_id and vid parameters.

Comment: Hi - correct url structure is updated. I just want any url ending with double dots to be redirected to home page i.e www.abc.com . Many thanks

Comment: OK that can be done. I will be reaching near my computer in few mins and post a solution.

Comment: Sure, awaiting !! Many thanks

Comment: Where did Google get these URLs from anyway – do you link to them anywhere on your page (or someone else from the outside)? I mean, random dots at the end of URLs don<Ät appear out of nowhere normally. As for the duplicate content problem – just specifying the canoncial URL of the resource via a `<link>` element would solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?.+?\.\.
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Many thanks, Works awesome. Just a small query - what does NE stands for in this one, as all previous redirects in my htaccess are having [R=301,L] . Regds

Comment: You're most welcome. NE is is for not encoding the special characters in URI. In this case I believe it will work with NE as well but when you're dealing with these weird URIs (2 dots or 2 ampersands etc) then NE flag comes handy.

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Have made a small edit, is the rule okay if we have to redirect all these pages ending with 2 dots or more to 404 page. PL advise. thnx

Comment: I checked your edit and that rule should work. Make sure you have setup a 404 page using `ErrorDocument 404` directive.

Comment: I have urls like http://www.example.com/apps/category/paramn2... - shortened links somewhere outside web with three dots at the end. It goes to 403 forbidden and i cant redirect it with above solutions. Any help?

Comment: These rules never returns 403 so your error might be due to other reasons. Please open a new question with details.