# How to redirect from URL with a trailing dot?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, drupal-7

Having a Drupal here. In that Drupal is a folder with another Drupal. So in another Drupal's .htacces the base was rewritten like this `Rewrite Base /another-drupal` and everything's fine.

Now, printed invitations were send to customers to look at the another Drupal via its URL `adrupal.com/another-drupal.` And like right now the URL stands at the end of a sentence and the dot looks like it is part of the URL. How do I redirect all users who entered the URL with a trailing dot to the correct URL without the trailing dot? And in which .htaccess do I have to do that? The parent's Drupal .htacess? Or in the another Drupal's .htaccess?

I allready tried that approach: [Redirect url to home page with trailing dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439705/redirect-url-to-home-page-with-trailing-dots), but it didn't work. Is it maybe because in that example they have two dots?

Comment: @user1281385 the dot is removed when the URI-path is canonicalized before it's put through the rewrite engine, that's why you need to match against the actual request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ .]*)\.(?:\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried! Works with ´adrupal.com/another-drupal/.´ (slash dot) but doesn't work with only the dot...

Comment: I'm sorry! Tried it again, this time in the parent Drupal's .htaccess and now it works! The first time I tried it in another Drupal's .htaccess...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this simple rule is all you need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

This will remove trailing period (dot) from any URL.